# Python exercise: lists sorting removing the nums

Tags: python

'Write a filter_ordered function that receives a list L1 of integers and returns a list L2 obtained starting from `L1`, eliminating all the elements that violate the growing order. In other words, an element of `L1` must be inserted in `L2` if and only if it is greater than all the elements that precede it in `L1`.

Example: If `L1 = [1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 3, 9]` then `filter_sorted (L1)` returns the list `L2 = [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9]`.'

this is my code:

```
def filtra_ordinati(l1):
    l2 = []
    for y in range(1,len(l1)):
        if l1[y-1] < l1[y]:
            l2.append(l1[y-1])
    return l2

L1 = [1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 3, 9]
print(filtra_ordinati(L1))
```

but gives me this output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 7, 3]
```

what did I do wrong? (only list comprehension should be used)

Comment: As a rule of thumb it is easier to iterate on elements (and eventually keepind the values needed to filter - here the last encountered element) than using range(len(..)))

Comment: Look at the 3. Should you keep it because it is smaller than 9? Or is there maybe something else you should be checking?

Comment: @KennyOstrom the output should be this: L2 = [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: Not too simple with one comprehension. IIUC `[x for e, x in enumerate(L1) if not e or x > max(L1[:e])]`

Comment: fid you find you error, you test for l1[y] but you appel l1[y-1]

Comment: Why do you say "only list comprehension should be used"? That's not in the task description. And you're not even doing that in your attempt.

Comment: Task asks for `filter_ordered`, then wants `filter_sorted`, and you wrote `filtra_ordinati`. Wow :-)

Comment: And now you accepted an answer that doesn't have a list comprehension...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
def filtra_ordinati(l1):
    l2 = []
    for y in range(1,len(l1)):
        if l1[y-1] < l1[y]:
            print(f'I will add {l1[y-1]} because it smaller then {l1[y]}')
            l2.append(l1[y-1])
    return l2

L1 = [1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 3, 9]
print(f'list is {L1}')
print(filtra_ordinati(L1))
```

And you will see what you adding inside list and why.

Output will be:

```
list is [1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 3, 9]
I will add 1 because it smaller then 2
I will add 2 because it smaller then 5
I will add 4 because it smaller then 7
I will add 7 because it smaller then 8
I will add 3 because it smaller then 9
[1, 2, 4, 7, 3]
```

The correct function is:

```
def f(l):
  l2 = l[:1]
  for el in l:
    if el > l2[-1]:
      l2.append(el)
  return l2
```

Comment: Better start with `l[:1]`, that won't crash for empty input.

Comment: @KellyBundy Here is no said about minimum list size so I skipped check, but yes, your way is more correct in theory. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative solution:

```
def filtra_ordinati(l1):
l2 = []

for i in range(0,len(l1)):
    if i == 0:
        l2.append(l1[i])
    if l1[i] > l1[i-1]:
        l2.append(l1[i])
return l2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not fancy solution but might be quicker than some as it limits the number of access by indices.

```
def filtra_ordinati(entries):
    if not entries: # take care of empty entry
        return

    ## initialization
    result = [entries[0]] # the first element is always included in the result

    ## process the entries list items: beginning with the second one
    # set max_value initial
    max_value= entries[0]        
    for entry in entries[1:]:

        if max_value < entry :
            result.append(entry)
            
            # set new max_value 
            max_value = entry

    return result
```

```
>>> L1 = [1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 3, 9]
>>> filtra_ordinati(L1)
[1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: @KellyBundy, I modified my answer. But I must have had an illusion because I was really sure that what was required was that n be greater than n-1, which incidentally surprised me.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with a comprehension in a call to .extend():

```
L1 = [1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 3, 9]

L2 = L1[:1]
L2.extend(n for n in L1[1:] if n > L2[-1])

print(L2)
[1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you're allowed to use libraries, you could use accumulate to get the running maximum and compare it to each position:

```
from itertools import accumulate
L2 = [n for n,m in zip(L1,accumulate(L1,max)) if n>=m]
```